# Finding a hotel booking site that really books the hotel (for Mumbai)

Tags: hotels, bookings, mumbai

I want to travel Mumbai and stay for one day there. I want to book a hotel for one day. I want to book a hotel online but can't find any suitable way of doing it.

Whenever I try to book a hotel, there is a customer review saying that they had done a booking through that site but on arrival, they had found no booking existing.

How can I find a hotel booking site that I can be sure makes a booking? Or is there any alternative way?

Comment: did you try http://www.booking.com ?

Comment: How are you trying to book a hotel? Where did you see the customer review you mentioned? Have you ever tried www.booking.com?

Comment: I tried ibibo.com is booking.com safe?@MeNoTalk

Comment: Safest would be to book directly through the hotel itself, either by phone or on the hotel's own website - did you try either of those?

Comment: No I did not do these

Comment: @learnmore booking.com is quite trustworthy and might be be the most famous site for booking hotel rooms out there..

Comment: thanks @MeNoTalk for your help.Then should I continue booking through it?

Comment: Mumbai is a big place with lots of hotels.  Since you're only staying a single night, why not just show up on the day and check in somewhere that looks good in person?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Few reliable options for you would be

- TripAdvisor
- Makemytrip
- Goibibo
- Expedia

But one thing which I always do after selecting a hotel from these sites is to check for the hotel's independent website and see if a booking option is available on it. If it is present, then a booking can be made easily through the hotel's page and you could confirm your booking over the phone.

If bookings are not permited or the website is not available, you can try getting the contact number from `Justdial` or simply by searching the hotel contact on google and then talk to them about the booking options and availability.

If somehow, you are not able to get to both of these things, you can eliminate this hotel from your selection and move to the next one! :)

All the best!

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since the question was asked. A majority of the hotels offer reliable booking online.
You may use local hotel aggregators like:

- [Make My Trip](https://www.makemytrip.com/)
- [Go Ibibo](https://www.goibibo.com/)
- [Yatra](https://www.yatra.com/)

Or from your preferred international ones:

- [Expedia](https://www.expedia.co.in/)
- [Booking](https://www.booking.com/country/in)
- [Trivago](https://www.trivago.in/)
- [Agoda](https://www.trivago.in/)

Also look out for budget stay in standardised rooms across cheap hotels using [Oyo Rooms](https://www.oyorooms.com/).

Major hotel chains like [The Taj Group](https://www.tajhotels.com), [Radisson Blu](https://www.radissonblu.com/en), [Marriott](https://www.marriott.com/hotel-search/india.hotels/) and other Accor hotels have their own websites where you may comfortably book your stay.

And lastly, [AirBnb](https://www.airbnb.co.in/) is an option too.